# jQuery not handling multiple changes to dom element

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a table that I am making changes to using jQuery.

I want to make 2 changes, the first to replace an element and then re-sort the table using tablesorter.

```
$("#sl" + myrec_id).replaceWith(result.html);
$("#scenario_item_list").tablesorter({ sortList: current_scenareoSort });
```

The issue is that if I do the table sort then the item is added to the table as a second row rather than replacing.

Each line works OK independently, but not together.

UPDATED : Here is the full code

```
$(".save_item_update" ).live("touchstart click",function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var mysc_id = $("#scenarioid").attr("class");
            var myrec_id = $("#recordid").attr("class");
            var loadtype = $("#edittype").attr("class");

            var fr_description = $("#fr_description").val();
            var fr_type = $("#fr_type").val(); 
            var fr_paymentfrequency = $("#fr_paymentfrequency").val(); 
            var fr_amount = $("#fr_amount").val(); 
            var fr_payhowtype = $("#fr_payhowtype").val(); 
            var fr_balance = $("#fr_balance").val(); 
            var fr_asatdata = $("#fr_asatdata").val(); 
            var fr_interestrate = $("#fr_interestrate").val();
            var sl_differentdata = $("#sl_differentdata").val(); 
            var sl_amount = $("#sl_amount").val(); 
            var sl_paymentfrequency = $("#sl_paymentfrequency").val(); 

            var fr_comment = $("#fr_comment").val(); 
            $.post("/scenario/save_item_update", { loadtype : loadtype, item_id : myrec_id, sl_scenario_id : mysc_id, fr_description:fr_description, fr_paymentfrequency:fr_paymentfrequency, fr_amount:fr_amount, fr_payhowtype:fr_payhowtype, fr_balance:fr_balance, fr_asatdata:fr_asatdata, fr_interestrate:fr_interestrate, fr_type:fr_type, fr_comment:fr_comment },
            function(result){

                if (result.status == "NOT LOGGED IN" ) {
                    NotLoggedIn(true);
                } else if (result.status == 'ERROR') {
                    ReportError(result.errormessage,true)
                } else {

                    if (loadtype == 'sl_remove') {
                        $("#finance_item_list tbody").append(result.html);
                        $("#sl" + myrec_id).remove();
                        $("#mthremain").html(result.monthremaining);
                        $("#finance_item_list").tablesorter({ sortList: current_financeSort });
                    } else if (loadtype == 'fi_dodelete') {
                        $("#fr" + myrec_id).remove();
                    } else if (loadtype == 'fi_use') {
                        $("#scenario_item_list tbody").append(result.html);
                        $("#mthremain").html(result.monthremaining);
                        $('#fr' + myrec_id).remove();
                        $("#scenario_item_list").tablesorter({ sortList: current_scenareoSort });
                        closePopUp();
                        $("#popup_body").html('');
                    } else if (loadtype == 'fi_edit') {
                        $("#fr" + myrec_id).replaceWith(result.html);
                        $("#finance_item_list").tablesorter({ sortList: current_financeSort });
                        closePopUp();
                        $("#popup_body").html('');
                    } else if (loadtype == 'sl_edit') {
                        $("#sl" + myrec_id).replaceWith(result.html);
                        $("#mthremain").html(result.monthremaining);
                        $("#scenario_item_list").tablesorter({ sortList: current_scenareoSort });
                        closePopUp();
                        $("#popup_body").html('');
                    } else if (loadtype == 'fi_insert') {
                        $("#finance_item_list tbody").append(result.html);
                        //$("#finance_item_list").tablesorter({ sortList: current_financeSort });
                        closePopUp();
                        $("#popup_body").html('');
                    }

                }

            },"json");
        });
```

Comment: Have you thought of using [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried....

Comment: Bobthyasin I haven't tried .queue but that looks interesting thanks.

Comment: Palash full code added. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to update the DOM.

You could do this within a on or previous live event.

EDIT:

I found this, might be helpful:

> I believe you can trigger an update using something like:

```
$(table).trigger("update")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand sorry. The main function is within a live function but not sure how it helps here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks MaggiQall, that doesn't work. In fact I can't find any documentation on the "update" trigger. Trigger yes, but not the update event.

Comment: Thanks Again MaggiQall. I have found examples today that are using the trigger update option. Seems like it should help but not in this case. It is actually looking more and more like its a bug/limitation in the tablesorter plugin itself.

Comment: glad if I could contribute with atleast something :